# CentOS scp without password not working

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, public-key

I have been trying to connect from one **EC2 instance** to another using ssh public keys and have been having a very tough time.

Here is the scenario: 
I need to have box 2 scp a file from box 1 in a script. This script will need to be able to scp without a password so I need to setup public keys.

On box 2 I ran `ssh-keygen –t rsa` and generated `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`
I copied `id_rsa.pub` to box 1
I moved `id_rsa.pub` to .ssh and ran `cat id_rsa.pug >> authorized_keys`
I changed permissions of all .ssh directory to *700* on both boxes and the files themselves to *600*.
I have changed the sshd_config settings on box 1 to:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
```

And then restarted ssh

```
/sbin/service sshd restart
```

When I try to scp or ssh into box1 from box1 I get the error:

```
Address 67.22.33.1 maps to ec2-67-22-33-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
tomcat@tomcat1.****.com's password:
```

Any ideas?

---

I made that change and tried scp to tomcat1 and it failed. Here is the output:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to tomcat1.****.com [67.22.33.15] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tomcat/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/tomcat/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
The authenticity of host 'tomcat1.****.com (67.22.33.15)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 5a:3e:fe:be:b8:0e:05:63:bf:ab:c8:4f:e5:91:db:a0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'tomcat1.****.com,67.22.33.15' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tomcat/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tomcat/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: What user did you setup the authorized keys for. On the remote box it needs to be for the user you're trying to connect as. An authorized key for root does NOT work all users.

Comment: Have you changed box 2's ssh_config so ssh *attempts* pubkey auth?

Comment: Also, I would run scp with the -v flag to get the verbose output.  This is very helpful with the debugging.

Comment: How do you change the config to attempt pubkey?

Answer (score 1):

Your authorized keys line should be

```
AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The server is looking in the wrong directory for your server.

Comment: Thanks for that catch. I made that change to my /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restarted /sbin/service sshd restart and I still can't connect.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE - FIXED IT**

```
restorecon -R -v -d /root/.ssh
```

This is a known issue with RH where directories get mislabelled and PAM prevends sshd from reading authorized_hosts when run as init script. You'll see the errors if you stumble across `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. Rare it seems but painful when it happens!

More details at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=499343

**ORIGINAL POST**

I've just hit what looks like exactly this problem. I had a poorly tuned VirtualBox (I hadn't told vbox to use 64bit) -- which when I cloned and restarted (in vbox RedHat 64-bit mode), started asking me for a password.

The original image was fine -- with identical settings -- so I think the suggestion of being networking-related might be relevant, or else to do with server keys.

The weird thing however is that if on the box, I kill the sshd process which autostarted, then manually run /usr/sbin/sshd as root, I can log in passwordless fine.  **A silly workaround, but usable.**

So it is an /etc/init.d/sshd issue.  But I haven't been able to track down what it is ... have tried chucking out most of the stuff in that script but it still prompts for password when invoked as `/etc/init.d/sshd start` but not when at `/usr/sbin/sshd`.

Maybe these comments can help, and someone can then help further!?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing box1 IP from ~/.ssh/known_hosts, so it renews. Perhaps ssh disables key authentication due to possible 'man in the middle' attack.

If it won't help, add line 

`GSSAPIAuthentication no`

in your /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.

Comment: his debug output does not mention GSS. I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will solve your problem and I use it to solve my ssh not login problem. The keypoint is to run
ssh root@node02 'restorecon -R -v /root/.ssh'
this command will fix SE
http://blog.firedaemon.com/2011/07/27/passwordless-root-ssh-public-key-authentication-on-centos-6/

Answer (score 0):

After following previous steps I had to set the permission to ".." in the .ssh folder:

Once I had for ~/.ssh:

drwx------ 2 build build 4096 Nov  4 14:35 .

drwx------ 6 build build 4096 Nov  4 14:34 ..

-rw------- 1 build build  400 Nov  4 14:35 authorized_keys

It worked!

Thanks. Damian

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and have been scratching my head for an entire afternoon.
It turned out to be a small sshd_config file issue.

first, change access mod on *.ssh* folder of the remote host to user access only.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

next, **go to /etc/ssh/sshd_config, change `StrictModes yes` to `StrictModes no`. If it's commented out, then specifically add `StrictModes no` into the file.**

That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

And one more thing I just found, I had to edit the .ssh/authorized_keys file to and make hostname fully qualified.   Otherwise, I couldn't use the fully qualified name in the scp/ssh command.  Now both fully qualified (like "host.company.com") & the relative name ("host") work, given that both hosts are in the "company.com" domain.  ssh-keygen created the public key file with just the hostname.